# How to save a dataframe as an element of a list and vice versa?

Tags: database, r, list, type-conversion, dataframe

Ok so i have a bunch of values in a 2*100 dataframe , i want this to be stored as a list which will be stored as an element of a dataframe again...

This means every dataframe will contain a column, each element of which will refer to a list containing a bunch of information

Is this possible ?

Comment: The data would be 4 columns each with some numeric data and a 5th column with lists. e.g. column 5 and row 1 should contain a list which will contain a 2*100 dataframe of locations associated with the row. This will be true for all elements of column 5. This dataframe would be needed later for a different algorithm.

Comment: Maybe you can use list of lists. Second list with vector of four numeric values and matrix 2 by 100 for location data.

Comment: In general:  `foo <- list(x=1:5,y=6:10,z='hello')` followed by `bar <- list(foolist=foo,barlist=list(a=11:15,b=16:20,cc='farewell'))` and so on ab adsurdium.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it sure is!  Try `I()`.

```
> df = data.frame(a=1:3,b=4:6)
> df
  a b
1 1 4
2 2 5
3 3 6
> DF = data.frame(A=I(list(df,df)),B=I(list(df,df)))
> DF
         A        B
1 1:3, 4:6 1:3, 4:6
2 1:3, 4:6 1:3, 4:6
> sapply(DF,class)
     A      B 
"AsIs" "AsIs" 
> sapply(DF$A,class)
[1] "data.frame" "data.frame"
> sapply(DF$B,class)
[1] "data.frame" "data.frame"
> DF[2,1]
[[1]]
  a b
1 1 4
2 2 5
3 3 6
```